# PyDev showing error icon in code completion popup

Tags: eclipse, jython, pydev

I installed PyDev using drag&drop into an existing Eclipse Mars.2 version. I then configured PyDev to use the Jython interpreter. If I now type python code and hit Ctrl+Space the expected popup opens, but the only option all the time is `org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/PyLinkedModeCompletionProposal` with the eclipse error icon next to it.
[image: popup screenshot]